# How to display Search Box in Every Page of the application in Mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to display search box  in every page of my application . I tried with Rendering as Partial view in layout.But its not working. Please any body suggest

/*Search Controller Code:*/

```
 public class SearchController : Controller
    {
       // Filtering the Search with product name
        public ActionResult SearchProduct(string SearchString)
        {
            FlipcartDBContext db = new FlipcartDBContext();

            var products = from p in db.Products select p;
            products = products.Where(s => s.ProductName.StartsWith(SearchString));
            return View(products);

             }


        // Return a Json Result
        public JsonResult GetProducts(string term)
        {
            FlipcartDBContext db = new FlipcartDBContext();
            List<string> products;

     products = db.Products.Where(s=>s.ProductName.StartsWith(term)).Select(x=>x.ProductName).ToList();

            return Json(products, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

/*SearchProduct.cshtml:*/

```
           jQuery(function ($) {

              $("#SearchString").autocomplete({
                                    source: '@Url.Action("GetProducts","Search")',
                                    minLength: 2,
                                });
                            });




        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
        <p>
            @Html.TextBox("SearchString", null, new { id = "SearchString" }) <br />

            <input type="submit" value="Search" id="Search" />
        </p>
    }
```

/*Displaying Product   */

```
     @foreach(var item in Model)
            {
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>/* Displaying Selected Product Detail */
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)
                        </td>
                        <td>
              <a href="@Url.Action("Details","Store",new{id=item.PkProductID})">here</a>
</td>
           </tr>
        </table>.
```

/*Please suggest ,am new to jquery and mvc.
    thanks in advance*/

Comment: Can you please provide the describe error message you are receiving?

Comment: Is that the Layout Page? The layout page cannot take a model input, only ViewBag/ViewData

Comment: I have formatted my post..Please have a look. And provide me suggestion.Do i need a ajax call to replace the content of each page with the SearchProduct view result. If so please helf me out with the ajax call

Answer (score 0):

bind a viewmodel with one property by the name SearchString to the partial view
replace

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
```

with

```
@model viewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm(actionName, contollerName, FormMethod.Post, new { id = id }))    
{
@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.SearchString)
<input type='submit'/>
}
```

where

controllerName is SearchController

actionName is SearchProduct

and in the SearchProduct method/action replace SearchString with viewModel